# Why I'm Getting Extra Undefined On Node JS

Tags: node.js

I Had Two File Here
First One Is app.js

```js
var msg = require('./msg.js');
console.log("Hello World From app.js")
console.log(msg());
```

Another Is msg.js

```js
var msg = function () { 
    console.log("Hello World From msg.js");
}
module.exports = msg;
```

While Running This On Console Via Command

```js
node app.js
```

Getting Output Like
Hello World From app.js
Hello World From msg.js
undefined

So my question is why there is extra `undefined` ? Is there something wrong in the way I created module? Is there a better way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `console.log(msg())` tries to print the values return by `msg()` and `msg()` doesn't return anything.

So, try to call `msg()`, rather than `console.log(msg())`.

```
var msg = require('./msg.js');
console.log("Hello World From app.js")
msg();
```

**Edit:** After comment,

msg.js

```
var msg = function () { 
  return "Hello World From msg.js"; 
}
module.exports = msg;
```

app.js

```
var msg = require('./msg.js');
console.log("Hello World From app.js")
console.log(msg());
```

Comment: got you or i can just return("Hello World From msg.js"); in msg.js

Comment: It doesn't return `null`, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: `null` is printed as `undefined` in javascript's `console.log` . Try to run the **Edit** code, it should not print `undefined`.

Comment: The OP's `msg()` function has no return value.  Therefore, it returns `undefined`.  Your answer says it returns `null`.  That is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code in app.js should be fixed to:

```
var msg = require('./msg.js');
console.log("Hello World From app.js")
msg();
```

You are invoking a function declared in another module you should not console log its output.

Comment: got you or i can just return("Hello World From msg.js"); in msg.js

Comment: You can also return "Hello World From msg.js"